# Can't animate keyframed node properties with f-curve - they are disabled

Tags: animation, keyframes, fcurves

I need a 'pulsing' light in my scene, so I have animated a material's emmission strength over a few frames and keyframed that with 'I'.

I want that infinitely repeating using f-curve since I need it pulsing throughout any length of animation, but f-curve is disabled in the Dope Sheet (see attached), and I see nothing in the Graph editor.

(In the Dope Sheet I select the keyframes and 'shift-E -> f-curve' but it does nothing)

Anyone seen this before? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I couldn't repeat it. Can you publish the blend file?

Comment: @Crantisz Blend file attached...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select current node, that you want to edit in f-curve editor:

[image]

or unclick  **only include channels related to selected objects and data** (icon with mouse pointer)

[image]

This features restore to default state:

[image]